# SQL query on two tables using two column as keys

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by, count

I started studying SQL (not MySQL as it seems to be different in some parts)
and I encountered this problem that i could not figure out how to solve

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    product char(30),
    color   char(30)
);

INSERT INTO products (product, color)
VALUES 
("table","brown"),
("chair","brown"),
("shelf","brown"),
("table","black"),
("chair","white");

CREATE TABLE suppliers(
    supplier char(30),
    product char(30),
    color   char(30)
);

INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier, product, color)
VALUES 
("s1","chair","brown"),
("s1","door","brown"),
("s1","table","brown"),
("s1","table","black"),
("s1","shelf","brown"),
("s2","chair","brown"),
("s3","table","brown"),
("s3","table","black"),
("s3","chair","brown"),
("s3","chair","white"),
("s3","shelf","white");
```

I need to find using SQL the suppliers and the number of brown products which they can provide to the store and **the store sells them**, ordered by the count as ascending (brown products in products table).
I started out with sub queries and something like this:

```
select supplier,COUNT(pb.product)
from (select product from products where color = "brown") as pb, (select supplier, product from suppliers where color = "brown") as sb
where pb.product == sb.product;
```

but I cannot figure it out, please help.

The results on these tables need to be:

```
supplier| no_of_products
-------------------------
   s2   |   1
   s3   |   2
   s1   |   3
```

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect. Stop trying to code your overall goal. Find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) Don't just dump wrong code. Give the least cut & paste & runnable code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I needed the following:

```
select supplier, COUNT(s.product)
From suppliers s, products p
WHERE s.product = p.product and s.color = "brown" and p.color = "brown"
GROUP by supplier
order by COUNT(s.product);
```

Comment: `select supplier, COUNT(s.product) as no_of_products`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want simple aggregation:

```
select supplier, count(*) no_brown_products
from suppliers 
where color = 'brown'
group by supplier
```

Comment: what is the order of execution in this query?

Comment: @Darknifem: I don't know what you mean by *oder of execution*...

Comment: I just realized i wasn't specific enough, the store has to sell these products, and the order has to be of the counting, i'm sorry

Comment: @Darknifem: please edit your question to show the results that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: I updated the tables data + added a result that is supposed to be, thank you

Comment: @Darknifem: thanks. You just need to add an `order by` clause at the end of the query: `order by no_brown_products`.

Answer (score 1):

Here an join query, hope it solve your problem

```sql
SELECT supplier,COUNT(pb.product)
FROM product pb
INNER JOIN supliers sp ON sp.color = pb.color
WHERE color = 'brown'
GROUP BY supplier;
```

Comment: when i tried to execute this query i got ambiguous column name: color, thanks for helping and i think @GMB made the magic happen

Comment: @Darknifem The best way is not to use a Varchar to compare column, it is to create a table Color with all the color and link them with a foreign key on the table product and suppliers